# How to style UIPickerView selection indicator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I would like to achieve the style of the selection indicator as the image below:-

[image]

Below is my code:-

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel* tView = (UILabel*)view;
    if (!tView)
    {
        tView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, pickerView.frame.size.height)];
        [tView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:APP_FONT_OPENSANS_LIGHT size:18]];
        [tView setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:65.0f/255.0f green:65.0f/255.0f blue:65.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];
        [tView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        tView.numberOfLines=1;
    }
    // Fill the label text here
    tView.text=@"Hello Moto";
//    pickerView.subviews[1].backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//    pickerView.subviews[2].backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return tView;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    UILabel *labelSelected = (UILabel*)[pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component];
    labelSelected.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0f;
    [labelSelected setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

}
```

It is not giving me what I want. Any solution to this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Didn't get what kind of customization you need for UIPickerView. Can you  please explain?

Comment: If you'r not comfortable with code then use xib and load it return to delegate that you't using.

Comment: @santak customization for the selection indicator. For example, the background color, the width, make it rounded corner. How can I achieve those ?

Comment: @SPUDERMAN You are showing UIPickerView on any action and showing selected value in TextField or Label. Do you need customization of the wheel or button as your attached image shows?

Comment: @santak okay easy question. How can I minimize the width of the Selection Indicator as the image above? It is now taking up the entire width of the screen.

Comment: you can use customized UITableView instead, find the center cell of the table view in did scroll method and apply the required the properties (corner radius, BG color, font color etc) of the label in the center cell